# "Range" object must move along when adding a new row

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to color different rows depending on an if-statement. Example:

```
    ' # 1

If (test = True) Then

    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:J1").Interior.Color = varColor1

Else

    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A1:J1").Interior.Color = varColor2

End If


    ' # 2

If (test2 = True) Then

    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:J2").Interior.Color = varColor1

Else

    Worksheets("sheet1").Range("A2:J2").Interior.Color = varColor2

End If

    ' # 3

    '...etc
```

My question is, if I add a new row in the excel sheet, the value of the "Range"  becomes incorrect. For instance, if I add a row between A and B the program will color the new inserted row (as this new inserted row becomes B) and the actual B row that I want to color is now C. How can I ensure that when a row is added, the correct row is still colored. Ofcourse I can change the "Range" values manually but I have a lot of them so it will take very long to change all, there must be another way to do it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you define a named range (Ctrl-F3) XL will expand the definition if you insert a column within that range.

```
Worksheets("sheet1").Range("test1_range").Interior.Color = varColor1
```

Be careful if you insert a column at left edge of the named range - it will not be included into the named range.